# Extract multiple values from fixed pattern string

Tags: regex, bash, awk, substring

I want to parse 3 pieces of information from the last bit of `wget` command output. For example:

```
2022-12-26 19:14:44 (13.7 Mb/s) - ‘somelibrary.min.js’ saved [1077022]
```

I was able to get the date/time since that is a fixed length. I am unable to extract the est. transfer speed (`13/7`) and file size (`1077022`) values.

```
STR="2022-12-26 19:14:44 (13.7 Mb/s) - ‘somelibrary.min.js’ saved [1077022]"
echo date/time is ${STR::19}
```

I imagine the remaining substring extractions will need to be done with the help of regular expressions, but I am unable to figure it out. Is there a viable path using only *nix utils like awk, sed, etc.?

I tried awk:

```
echo "(13.7 Mb/s)" | awk '$0 ~ /(.* Mb\/s)/ {print $1}'
```

But I am getting `(13.7` instead of just the number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this with bash's regular expression matching, using `( )` in the RE to capture the relevant parts and `${BASH_REMATCH[n]}` to get them:

```
str="2022-12-26 19:14:44 (13.7 Mb/s) - ‘somelibrary.min.js’ saved [1077022]"

pattern='([-0-9]+ [:0-9]+) \(([^)]+)\) .*\[([0-9]+)\]'
if [[ "$str" =~ $pattern ]]; then
    echo "date/time is ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    echo "transfer speed is ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    echo "file size is ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
else
    echo "The string is not in the expected format"
fi
```

BTW, I recommend using lower- or mixed-case variable names to avoid conflicts with the many all-caps names with special functions, and running your scripts through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) to find common mistakes.

Answer (score 6):

This `awk` should work for you:

```bash
s="2022-12-26 19:14:44 (13.7 Mb/s) - ‘somelibrary.min.js’ saved [1077022]"
awk -F '[][()[:blank:]]+' '{
  printf "DateTime: %s %s, Speed: %s, Size: %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $(NF-1)
}' <<< "$s"

DateTime: 2022-12-26 19:14:44, Speed: 13.7, Size: 1077022
```

**Breakdown:**

- `-F '[][()[:blank:]]+'` sets 1+ of `[` or `]` or `(` or `)` or a whitespace as input field separator

Comment: I am getting the output `DateTime: 2022-12-26 19:14:44 (13.7 Mb/s) - ‘somelibrary.min.js’ saved [1077022] , Speed: , Size: 2022-12-26 19:14:44 (13.7 Mb/s) - ‘somelibrary.min.js’ saved [1077022]`

Comment: [See this working demo](https://ideone.com/8D7QXp)

Answer (score 6):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EGrkAq/1) for used regex.

```bash
s="2022-12-26 19:14:44 (13.7 Mb/s) - ‘somelibrary.min.js’ saved [1077022]"

awk '
match($0,/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) \(([^)]*).*\[([0-9]+)/,arr){
  print "DateTime: "arr[1] ", Speed: " arr[2] ", Size: "arr[3]
}
' <<< "$s"
```

Comment: The online demo works, but the above code throws an error `awk: line 2: syntax error at or near ,`.

Comment: @WebUser, This is a tested code in GNU `awk`. Request you to kindly do check your `awk` version once, run a `awk -v` command once and see what it gives, cheers.

Answer (score 5):

### Using Perl and [*named capture groups*](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#PCRE/Python-Support):

```
s="2022-12-26 19:14:44 (13.7 Mb/s) - ‘somelibrary.min.js’ saved [1077022]"

perl -nE '
    say join "\n",
    map { "$_: $+{$_}" }
    keys %+
    if m/
        (?<dateTime>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+\(
        (?<speed>\d+\.\d+).*\[
        (?<size>\d+)
    /x
' <<< "$s"
```

### Output

```
speed: 13.7
dateTime: 2022-12-26 19:14:44
size: 1077022
```

### Explanations

See [regex101 description](https://regex101.com/r/v8853a/1)

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed` with 3 capture groups `\1`, `\2` and `\3` in the replacement:

```
sed -E 's/([^()]+) \(([^()]*)\).*\[([^][]*)]/date\/time: \1\nspeed: \2\nfile size: \3/' file
```

The pattern matches:

- `([^()]+)`  Capture **group 1**, match any character except for `()`
- `\(([^()]*)\)` Between `(...)` capture any char except `(` and `)` in **group 2**
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `\[([^][]*)]` Between `[...]` Capture any char except `[` and `]` in **group 3**

See the capture group values here on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NLyrI9/1)

Output

```
date/time: 2022-12-26 19:14:44
speed: 13.7 Mb/s
file size: 1077022
```